# php lessons/practice. need help understanding if/else

Tags: php

ok so im here trying to practice some php (im a super beginner) and so long story short,
i put form elements in one page, passed it to the process php. 
Im just messing aound trying to see what ive learned so far. i dont get any errors, just dont understand why it doesnt work.

```
<?php 

$yourname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$compname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['compName']);

$response = array("please enter correct information","hmm" . "$yourname");

function nametest() {
if (!isset($yourname)){
    $yourname = $response[0];}
    else { 
    $yourname = $response[1];;
    }
}
?>


<?php  nametest(); ?>
```

what im trying to do is, that if the name isnt set, to make a variable equal to a value inside response.

Comment: You should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function nametest() {
    if (!isset($yourname)){
        $yourname = $response[0];
    } else { 
        $yourname = $response[1];
    }
    return $yourname;
}
print nametest();
```

The function needs to return a value to be printed. I also noticed you have two ;; behind line 5.

Comment: and yes, the below answer is correct.. $response is not known by nametest(), you either need to pass it in with nametest($response) or declare it as global.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning `$yourname` and `$compname` in the first two lines:

```
$yourname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$compname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['compName']);
```

**UPDATE** You can check if these are set in POST, and therefore not need to check them later:

```
$yourname = isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : "oops, no value";
$compname = isset($_POST['compName']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['compName']) : "oops, no value";
```

They will always be set, even if NULL or empty.  So, your later calls to `isset()` will always be true.
Instead, you may check if they are empty with the `empty()` function:

**UPDATE** Not necessary according to corrections in comments. Your `isset()` should work.

```
// Check with empty()
// but still won't work properly. keep reading below...
function nametest() {
if (!empty($yourname)){
    $yourname = $response[0];}
    else { 
    $yourname = $response[1];;
    }
}
```

However, there is another problem here of variable scope.  The variables are not available inside the function unless you either pass them in as parameters or use the `global` keyword:

```
// $yourname is passed as a function argument.
function nametest($yourname, $response) {
  if (!empty($yourname)){
      $yourname = $response[0];}
  else { 
      $yourname = $response[1];;
    }
}
```

Getting there... Now your function assigns `$yourname`, but it doesn't return or print any value.  Add a return statement,  and then you can echo out the result:

```
function nametest($yourname, $response) {
  if (!empty($yourname)){
      $yourname = $response[0];}
  else { 
      $yourname = $response[1];;
    }

  // Add a return statement
  return $yourname;
}

// Now call the function, echo'ing its return value
echo nametest($yourname, $response);
```

Comment: According to [PHP.net docs `isset()` should check for `NULL`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Also you lost parameter in the last line.

Comment: i thought that, although i set $yourname to equal the data that would be passed from the form on prev page, that thats what i was checking for as far as being empty or not.  so although i do understand what you are saying about the $yourname still being set to equal the $_GET method, then i should check the $_GET itself? and then if it IS set, then asign its value to something else?

Comment: @somdow you can check if the `$_POST` value `isset()` and that's how I would probably do it most of the time.  See an addition up near the top of my post

Answer (score 0):

Variable Scope is the biggest mistake here, your function can not 'see' the variables that you created outside of it, do this:

```
<?php
    .
    .
    .
function nametest($yourname, $response) { // This creates two new variables that
                                          // are visible only by this function
    if (!isset($yourname)){
        $yourname = $response[0];
    } else { 
        $yourname = $response[1]; // Get rid of the extra semicolon
    }

    return $yourname; // This $yourname is only visible by this function so you
                          // need to send it's value back to the calling code
}
?>


<?php  nametest($yourname, $response); ?> // This sends the values of the 
                                          // variables that you created at the
                                          // top of this script
```

Comment: hi there, and thanks. ok no matter which version of code i try i get the same result which is 

    $response = array("please enter correct information","welcome" . ", " . $yourname);

with this line, no matter which code block i try, when i hit the submit button on my form, with nothing entered in the name field, in all this code provided, i should get response [0], which is "enter correct info" but i dont, instead i get "welcome".

then when i reload the page and enter in my name "somdow", i get "welcome somdow "
isnt that wrong? and again, no matter which one i try, i get the same results.

Comment: You can try changing !isset($yourname) to $yourname == '' , it is most likely being set when the variable is being passed even it is null, you can also try empty($yourname)